# How To Rollback A Migration Using IMigrator?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I apply migrations using the IMigrator as shown below:

```
var pending = this.GetPendingMigrations(dbContext);
var pendingEnumerable = pending as string[] ?? pending.ToArray();
if (pendingEnumerable.Contains(request.MigrationName))
{
    await migrator.MigrateAsync(request.MigrationName);
}
```

We are trying to rollback a migration using the below:

```
var applied = await dbContext.Database.GetAppliedMigrationsAsync();
var enumerable = applied.ToList();
var indexOfThisMigration = enumerable.IndexOf(request.MigrationName);
if (indexOfThisMigration > 0)
{
    var rollbackTo = enumerable[indexOfThisMigration - 1];
    await migrator.MigrateAsync(rollbackTo);
}
```

The `applied` has all the migrations ever applied.  Currently it has about 750 migrations with an abbrievated list below:

```
20180211052447_Init
...
20220301044856_MigrationUpgradeToEf6
20220301052416_TestRollback1
```

We are attempting to rollback (remove) migration `20220301052416_TestRollback1`.  With logging, we know that the variable `rollbackTo` is `20220301044856_MigrationUpgradeToEf6`.

When we call `await migrator.MigrateAsync(rollbackTo)` (with rollbackTo value of `20220301044856_MigrationUpgradeToEf6`), it does not remove `20220301052416_TestRollback1`.  The logs contain the below:

```
[Information] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations:
No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.
```

We had this issue with EF Core 5.x and upgraded to 6.0.2 to see if this issue might have been fixed.

This is all for MS SQL Server.

How do we rollback to `20220301044856_MigrationUpgradeToEf6`?

Comment: Did you have any solution to fix that?

Comment: It turned out it was actually a CloudFormation problem.  CloudFormation rolls back the entire binary for a lambda function before calling delete on the CustomResource, therefore the "new" migration was not there to rollback and the database really was up to date.